# What does Path.transform(Matrix) do to a line?

Tags: android, matrix, graphics

What calculations happen when I execute the following code? The source code of both classes refer to native methods, unfortunately.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(20,20);
path.lineTo(40,20);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(2,2,50,50);
path.transform(matrix);
```

What I want to do, is move some text with it. For example,

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

What calculations would I have to do to keep the text left aligned with the line? Note that I do not want to resize the text, only move it.

Comment: Is **path transform="matrix(** HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same matrix when drawing the text.  Canvas has a setMatrix method.

Comment: Wouldn't that enlargen the text as well?

Comment: I've tried it, unfortunately this scales the text size as well.

Comment: Then draw with a smaller text size set.  Or you can try creating a new matrix with the same pivot point but a 1 scale factor

Comment: Drawing with a smaller text size doesn't work, as the text is stretched unproportionally. Using a pivot point without scaling or anything doesn't do anything to a matrix.

Comment: Use the pivot point but not the scaling.  That would create a translation matrix.  But probably a better solution is just to use mapPoint on the matrix created above to find the position to print to.

Comment: `Matrix.mapPoints(float[])` seems to do the trick, thanks! Perhaps you could edit this into your answer?

Comment: what is Canvas?

Comment: @user610620 Canvas is the object you use to draw a view to the screen. One is passed into your onDraw function when a view draws itself.

Comment: Canvas is a software or device? not sure what onDraw is either

Comment: @user610620 Canvas is a class in the Android framework.  onDraw is a function on a View object.  I suggest you read up on how the Android rendering system works, it seems like you're starting from absolute zero.